# How to when input on focus the div element should scale (grow) in its size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried adding Event listener

```
    const inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.input-field');
const innerContainer = document.querySelector('.inner-container');

inputField.addEventListener('click', function(){
  innerContainer.style.transform.scale(1.1);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if you want to trigger an eventListener on focus then add the `focus` event not `click`. 
I'd suggest always keep checking the console when you're playing with css

The way you're adding eventListener on inputField is wrong. `inputField` returns an array of nodes, so if to add eventlListener on these use for loop on `inputField` and then style the div.

Another mistake is the way you're adding the `transform` style. In js to add style you've to give the strig. Right way is `innerContainer.style.transform = 'scale(1.1)'` or `innerContainer.style= 'transform :scale(1.1)'`.

```js
const inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
const innerContainer = document.querySelector('.tr');

for (let i = 0; i < inputField.length; i++) {
  inputField[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
    innerContainer.style = 'transform :scale(1.1)'
  });
}
```

```css
.tr {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="tr">
  <input type="text" placeholder="input" class="input">
</div>
```

If you want to scale only on focusing on the input then create a class for scaled css and toggle that class on focusing and on blur.

```js
const inputField = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
const innerContainer = document.querySelector('.tr');

for (let i = 0; i < inputField.length; i++) {
  inputField[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
    innerContainer.classList.add('grow')
  });
  inputField[i].addEventListener("blur", function() {
    innerContainer.classList.remove('grow')
  });
}
```

```css
.tr {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

.grow {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="tr">
  <input type="text" placeholder="input" class="input">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your help. :) Cheers

Comment: Are you kidding me! Yes! :D When adding the transition properties to ease a bit the moving states where to add them?

Comment: add it in `grow` class